# Task Scheduler starts my programs hidden (No GUI)

Tags: task-scheduler

I've made a task with an action to start a batch file, which this batch first kills all processes that has a particular name and then starts them again.

The problem is after the start all processes starts hidden and i can't watch their GUI's (console window) in order to monitor them.

Is it possible to make them start normally? If not what other options do i have?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if the task was configured to run under `SYSTEM` account. Right-click the Task and click Properties. Click `Change User or Group` and choose `Administrators` or the user account under which you want the task to run.